# Alert user for unsaved changes in page within panels using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a situation here, i need to stop the user if user has left some unsaved changes on the page.

I got some information over the internet for moving from current page to other page like

```
var warnMessage= "You have unsaved changes";
$('input:not(:button,:submit),textarea,select').change(function () {
                window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                    if (warnMessage != null) return warnMessage;
                };
            });

            $('input:submit').click(function(e) {
                warnMessage = null;
            });
```

This works fine when we are closing tab or URL is getting changed.

I have panels on my page as like three different panels;each with a Submit, Cancel and Reset. Now, i need to alert the user when it happens to open a panel; last panel has unsaved changes then user should be alerted

If he/she has some unsaved changes on the panel, submit/reset/cancel button is clicked then also it should confirm by the user.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are multiple panels visible at once, or just one at a time?

Comment: First, remove nested onbeforeunload handler and put it outside change event

Comment: @PhonicUK: One at a time...

Comment: @roasted: Y so?? Any reasons behind it?

Comment: Because each time change event is fired you add an new onbeforeunload handler to window object. This means if onbeforeunload  is fired, you could call its attached handler 100 times which is calling for problem

Comment: Den where should i put that.. with call of it

Comment: @roasted Each subsequent call should override the previous, i don't see a problem with how he has it. http://jsfiddle.net/aBMNn/ although it doesn't really *need* to be inside the change event.

Comment: @KevinB you are right, he's not using jquery to attach handler, sorry for mistake

Comment: People: I want to have the alert/confirm box working on click of buttons rather than leaving webpage...